# How detect failure of Web Performance Test run from command line

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, performance-testing

I've got a visual studio 'web performance test' to run from the command line. The plan is to create a scheduled task to run this. How do i trigger an email on failure? Either I wire that logic up in the test itself or it's external and dependent on return code but i don't think there is a return value - i.e. failure is shown in output text or by checking the saved results file.

Comment: i did determine that by using the /usestderr switch on mstest it is possible to detect test failure in a batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `/resultsfile:[ file name ]` option with `mstest.exe` to create a ".trx" file. Its contents is XML and it contains a section similar to:

```
<ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="1" executed="1" passed="1" error="0" failed="0"
              timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0"
              notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0"
              completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
</ResultSummary>
```

(Extra white space added for clarity).

It should be a simple matter to examine the TRX file after the run and send an email if anything failed.

Comment: thanks. i basically use /usestderr and check results from batch file (or VBS script file). of course i don't get detailed fail reasons that way so you're path is a good one for me to move up to :)